# Add and remove to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i'm creating a list with add to favorite link.
I want to store the 'foo' value on local storage using pure JS. Then once I click again it is remove.
Maybe I can not bind the identifier to the style name.
I wanted to repeat the way it is here https://jsfiddle.net/farhadB/ocgcejg2/ , but I can’t.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('photo')) {
    e.target.classList = "foo";
  } else if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('foo')) {
    e.target.classList = "photo";
  }
});
```

Comment: `classList` is a list of classes, you're trying to assign a string to it... That can't be right, now can it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is, that you are setting the `classList`. `classList` is a [readonly attribut](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and you can add classes by using the `add` method.

Maybe you mean instead of:

```js
e.target.classList = "photo";
```

This:

```js
e.target.className = "photo";
```

or

```js
e.target.classList.add("photo");
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use Add and Remove, I can’t change the class back.
https://codepen.io/insomikk/pen/vYNPJoY   - full code

Comment: In the codepen it does not work, because you haven't set any listitem with a class. Therefore the click event will not really do anything. When you add the class `photo` to all list items, it will work just fine. There is just a styling issue.

Answer (score 0):

For more than one link you need

```
let store;   
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const photo = tgt.classList.contains('photo');
  const foo   = tgt.classList.contains('foo');
  if (foo || photo) {
    tgt.classList.toggle("foo",photo);
    tgt.classList.toggle("photo",foo);
    store = [...document.querySelectorAll(".foo").map(ele => ele.id)
    localStorage.setItem('store',JSON.stringify(store));
  }
});
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store')) || [];
  store.forEach(id => {
    const ele = document.getElementById(id);
    ele.classList.add("foo");
    ele.classList.remove("photo");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('photo')) {
    e.target.classList.add("foo");
    e.target.classList.remove("photo");
    localStoarge.favlink = <link name here>;
  } else if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('foo')) {
    e.target.classList.add("photo");
    e.target.classList.remove("foo");
    localStoarge.favlink = null; // Delete fav link
  }
});
```

Comment: `if(e.target.classList.contains('...'))` is redundant - you already determined that - also you have typos